# On selection of C:\CustomFolder install path, the install path should be subfolder C:\CustomFolder\Parent\Child

Tags: installation, inno-setup

When the user *Changes* the installation folder, for example to `C:\CustomFolder`, my Inno Setup based installer should use the following subfolder for installation instead: `C:\CustomFolder\Parent\Child`.

What I found so far is that there is the [`AppendDefaultDirName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appenddefaultdirname) option, which appends the last component of [`DefaultDirName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_defaultdirname.htm) to the selected folder name. But this isn't the behaviour I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `{app}\Parent\Child` everywhere in the script, instead of plain `{app}`.

- You can create a [preprocessor define](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) for that to avoid repetitions.
- You may also want to move uninstall files to those subfolders using [`UninstallFilesDir` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallfilesdir).

```
#define TheAppPath "{app}\Parent\Child"

[Setup]
UninstallFilesDir={#TheAppPath}

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{#TheAppPath}"
Source: "MyProg.dat"; DestDir: "{#TheAppPath}"
```